# how to create a snapshot in android google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I know this question may seem basic , but I literally have no idea how to actually create a snapshot and I didn't find any documentation in Google play services on how to do it. Please excuse & tell me if I unacknowledged or missed something

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by 'snapshot'

Comment: Check out the [Adding Saved Games to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames), this guide shows you how to use the Saved Games API in an Android application. The API can be found in the com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot package. But know that before you can use the Saved Games service, you must first enable access to it. To do so, call EnableSnapshots() when you create the service with gpg::GameServices::Builder. This will enable the additional auth scopes required by Saved Games at the next auth event.

Comment: I've enabled it already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably already seen this: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames it doesn't give a complete picture, but this sample code by Google should help you: https://github.com/gguuss/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/CollectAllTheStars2

It goes through a complete game, that saves and retrieves snapshots using Google Play Games Services.

Comment: Thanks alot for showing me this example it helped me

Comment: Keep in mind you can store any of your local data to a byte array (mandatory data type for saved game snapshots) using java serialization, this is also not mentioned anywhere in Google docs if you don't have prior knowledge on serialization.

Comment: To be honest,  I don't save stuff in byte arrays I usually save variables without changing their data type except for bitmaps , I save their Uri in a bundle